# NFS mount of /var/www to OS X

Tags: mac, nfs

I have spent 2 hours trying to create an NFS mount from my Ubuntu 10.04 LTS server to my OS X desktop system.

Objective: three way file compare between the code base on the Mac, the development system on the local Linux test system, and the hosted website.

The hosted service uses cpanel so I can mount a webdisk - easy as pie - took 10 seconds.

The local Ubuntu box, on the other hand - nothing but pain and frustration.

Here is what I have tried:

1. In File Browser,

   - navigate to /var/www/site and right-click.
   - Select share this folder.
   - Enter sharename wwwsite and a comment.
   - Click button "Create Share".
   - Message says - you can only share file systems you own.  There is a message on how to fix this, but the killer is that this is sharing by SMB.  It will change the LFs to CR-LFs which will affect the file comparison.  So forget this option.
2. In a terminal window,

   - run shares-admin (I have not been able to convince it to give me the "Shared Folders" option in the System Administration window - Maybe it is somewhere else in the menu, but I cannot find it)
   - define an NFS export.
   - Enter the path /var/www/site, select NFS enter the ip address of the iMac and save.  On the mac, try to mount the file system using the usual methods  - finder, command line "mount" command - not found.  Nothing.  Tried restarting the linux box in case there is a daemon that needs restarting - nothing.

So I have run out of stuff to do.  I have tried searching the documentation - it is pretty basic.  The man page documentation is as opaque as ever.

Please, oh please, will someone help me to get this thing to work!
Thanks for reading this far...
PG.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see, /var/www is owned by someone else (probably root). 
To resolve this :
 Using Alt+F2 or the terminal, run `gksudo nautilus`. Ubuntu then shall ask you for your password. Nautilus will now open as root.

Navigate to the /var directory.

Right click on the folder "www" and select properties.

Browse to the "Permissions" tab.

Make this dialog box look like the screen shot below :
[image]

Here, "vibhav" (which is my user name) will be replaced by the user name through which you want to share the directory.

Click on "Apply Permissions to Enclosed Files"

Click on "Close"

Now , as a normal user, launch the File Browser.

Navigate to /var/www/site and right-click.

Select share this folder.

Enter sharename wwwsite and a comment.

Click button "Create Share

This shall share the folder over your network.